# Error importing R libraries into python, even after installing through ry2

Tags: python, r, package, python-import, rpy2

This is my code:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
import rpy2.robjects.packages as rpackages
utils = rpackages.importr('utils')
utils.install_packages('C50')
utils.install_packages('rlang')
rlang = rpackages.importr('rlang')
C50 = rpackages.importr('C50')
```

However, I get an error "PackageNotInstalledError: The R package "rlang" is not installed." on line 6 (the one that says to import rlang). However, I just installed it in the previous line. Do you have any idea why python believes it is not installed? Also, the answer to this question: [Importing rugarch R library into python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63148709/importing-rugarch-r-library-into-python), did not work in my case.

I tried installing rlang through Rstudio and running jupyter notebook as an administrator but nothing worked.I also tried the solution from this question: [Importing rugarch R library into python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63148709/importing-rugarch-r-library-into-python), but it did not work at all.

Comment: It seems very odd to have the line `utils.install_packages('rlang')` truly succeed with the next line `rlang = rpackages.importr('rlang')` failing. Note that R's `install_packages()` execution might complete without an R error but the installation have failed. Inspect the installation logs printed to the console. I suspect that it failed and the reason why are there.